# Get pairs of lines and multiply

Tags: bash, text-processing, arithmetic

I'm trying to parse an html file for some values using bash. So I've got a big text file with numbers like this

```
3
2
4
2
```

What I want to do is get two lines, multiply both numbers and then store the value on a variable and add it to a total. In this case it would be `3*2=6` and `4*2=8`. So `X=0, X=X+6, X=X+8`then`X=14`.

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
xargs -n2 < file | while read x y; do ((X+=x*y)); echo $X; done
```

- `xargs -n2`: groups numbers in pairs
- `read x y`: store first and second number in variables `x` and `y`
- `((...))` is just a arithmetic evaluation in bash

You will see on the screen how sum is growing.

Comment: Why not `X=$((X+x*y))`? or even terser `((X+=x*y))`?  Or if you want to be explicit about operator precedence `X=$(( X + (x * y) ))`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You are correct this is simpler, I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `paste` and `bc` to do what you want:

```
$ paste -d"*" - - <file.txt | paste -d"+" - - | bc
14
```

#### Breakdown

Here we can see that `paste` is taking 2 at a time and is putting a multiplication sign between them.

```
$ paste -d"*" - - <file.txt
3*2
4*2
```

A similar approach can be used to include the multiplication signs:

```
$ paste -d"*" - - <file.txt | paste -d"+"
3*2+4*2
```

Finally the finished string can be passed to `bc` to perform the mathematical operations.

```
$ paste -d"*" - - <file.txt | paste -s -d'+' | bc
14
```

The use of `paste` in the above commands varies. When performing the merging of the lines to form the X*Y we tell paste to take 2 lines (denoted as the dashes: <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>). In the 2nd case we're using `paste` to take the entire series of characters and incorporate a <kbd>+</kbd> in between each atom.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `awk` solution (assuming an even number of lines)

```
 awk '{y=$0; getline x; var += x*y};END{print var}' file.txt
```